# Dojo OnKeyPress Handler: TextBox value is blank

Tags: dojo

I have a Dojo form that does not contain a submit button.  Instead, I added an onkeypress handler to calls a method when Enter is pressed.  The problem I am having is that when I hit enter before blurring off the current field, the _process method thinks that field is empty.

Or in other words: type in field1.  hit tab.  type in field2.  hit enter.  field2 is blank unless i click off the field or shift-tab back.

Any ideas?

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("fkrform"),"onKeyPress",function(e) {                 
    if (e.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
        _process();
    }
```

and the method it calls:

```
function _process()
{
    var field1 = dijit.byId("field1").value;
    var field2 = dijit.byId("field2").value;
    alert(username);
    alert(password);

    ...do stuff...
}
```

The fields are of dojoType: dijit.form.TextBox, and the form is: dijit.form.Form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dijit.byId('field1').get('value')` instead of directly try to access the property "value". In your example you saved the value in the variable `field1` and `field2` and in the alert you use the variable `username` and `password` could be the answer why you don't get anything. But you still should use the `get` method to get a property instead of directly access the property.

When you press "Enter" your form will submit. So you need to connect to the "onSubmit" event on the form, instead of `onkeyPress` or `onKeyUp`.

The first example i created prints the value of the input box on every key someone pressed in the console.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8FHg/

But what you really wanted was hooking into the submit. I modified the example. The new example connects to "onSubmit" and creates an alert box with the text of the user input.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8FHg/1/

For completness if jsfiddle doesn't work some day. You JavaScript should looks like this.

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    var form = dijit.byId('form');
    var box  = dijit.byId('box');

    var submit = function(event) {
        dojo.stopEvent(event);
        alert("User input was " + box.get('value'));
    };

    dojo.connect(form, 'onSubmit', submit);
});
```

Assuming your form in your HTML has the id `form` and your box have the id `box`.

Comment: issue was caused by deprecated use of getting a value...using attr('value') fixed that.  your submit method is much better, will convert to that...thanks!